# Is it possible to make association with running services and it processes via powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to make association with running services and it processes via powershell? How can I do association in hashtable, example  @{ service1 = process1 ; service2 = process1 }

Comment: You can combine `Get-CimInstance win32_service` with `Get-Process` by the `ProcessID = ID` property.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Get-Service |Join (Get-Process) -On Name -eq ProcessName -Property Status, ID, Name, DisplayName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Service = $_
        Process = Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId
    }
}
```

Or you can do some custom output

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service | ForEach-Object {
    $process = Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ServiceName   = $_.Name
        ServiceStatus = $_.Status
        ServiceState  = $_.State
        ServicePath   = $_.PathName
        ProcessId     = $_.ProcessId
        ProcessName   = $process.Name
        ProcessPath   = $process.Path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, since you're only asking for `Service` & `Process` I'm assuming you only want their **Names**. So here is one way you could do it:

```
$map = @{}

Get-CimInstance win32_service | Group-Object ProcessID |
ForEach-Object {
    
    $proccess = Get-Process -ID $_.Name
    
    foreach($service in $_.Group.Name)
    {
        if($map.ContainsKey($service))
        {
            $map[$service].Add($process.Name)
            continue
        }

        $map.Add($service,$proccess.Name)
    }
}
```

Usage would be as any other *hashtable*, you provide the **`Service Name`** as key and it will return the associated **`Process Name`** as value:

```
PS /> $map[($map.Keys|Get-Random)]
lsass

PS /> $map[($map.Keys|Get-Random)]
SearchIndexer

PS /> $map[($map.Keys|Get-Random)]
Idle

PS /> $map[($map.Keys|Get-Random)]
svchost
```